# java multithreading with runnable interface

Tags: java, multithreading

Hi i have two threads running under the JButton action event. The first thread produces output that will be used by the second thread. Sometimes this produces the results i want and sometimes its jus goes way off. I understand that in order for me to get the correct results i must add synchronised as well as wait() and notify(). i have little idea of how to do this.Can someone by way of code please help me understand how to do this. here is what i have done so far.

```
       Thread t1;
       Thread t2;
       t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fillP(); // this method produces a string which would be used by the query running in thread 2
        }
    });
        t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String search = txtOFOCOde.getText();
            String sql = "Select * from APP.OFOOCCUPATION where OFOOCCUPATIONCODE = '"+search+"'";
try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);){
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
            String add1 = rs.getString("OFOOCCUPATIONNAME");
            OFOOccupation.setText(add1);
        }
    }


    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Person.this, e);
}    
        }
    });
    t1.start();
    t1.notify();
    try {
        t2.wait();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Person.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    t2.start();
```

am confused on where and how to put the synchronised method.

For clarity i will give you the full scenario of y situation i have a form which collects employees data. my problems comes form that method fillP() is run has a query that populates a combobox and a textbox with database values e.g ITC MANAGER being the value of the combobox and 220108 value of the textbook which is his specialisation code. Still on the same form the 3rd textbook will be filed in by the second query in thread 2. this is supposed to be done instantaneously because textbox 3 can only be populated once they is a value in textbox 2 which comes from thread 1

the form loads and while its loading the method FillP() in thread 1 and the query in thread 2 have to run so that after initialisation when the form is visible to the user all 3 control i.e.. combobox, and the 2 textbooks will be populated by data all streaming from two different tables of the database. The Combo and 1st textbook get their input from JobSpecialisation table and the 3rd textbox gets its input from the occupation table.

Comment: I am confused on what you are trying to achieve ...

Comment: Why are you using two threads? Why can't you have `fillP()` be executed right before `String search = ...`?

Comment: I strongly recommend to read [Java doc concurrency](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/) if you want to get used to concurrent threading

Comment: `OFOOccupation.setText(add1);` If this is setting a GUI Element, you should not do this from another thread than the EDT.

Comment: @Olivier Gregoire because if i execute them in sequence textbook three does not get populate it remains blank and i get a null point value error

Comment: Herb, we only can see what you show us. But it seems your "design" suffers from multiple side-effects. You need to eliminate those. Meaning you need to introduce at least MVC. Separate Model from View or you'll end up in maintainance-hell.

Answer (score 2):

Do you absolutely have call your code in different threads ? Seems to me that the code in t1 and t2 should juste be executed sequentially (i.e. do what t1 do, then do what t2 do in the same thread).

If you absolutely want to wait for the completion of t1 before executing t2, the best way is to use join (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/join.html). The join method simply wait for the completion of athread then process the following code.

At the end of your code do :

```
t1.start();
try {
    t1.join();//wait for t1 to complete
} catch (InterruptedException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(Person.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
t2.start();
```

There is some bad design in your code, but this should do the trick for what you want to achieve.

Comment: @ Mathias this works but not in the manner i want i get the exact values i require but the comboBox is now populate with a single value from the db more like jCombobox1.add instead of a recursive population so a user won't be able to select a different value from the combobox while when it was jus t1.start() and t2.start() i would get it working properly but producing wrong results

Comment: Where is the populated combobox in your code ? What is "txtOFOCOde", what is OFOOccupation ? I can help you with your code, but to be honest you should rework it, because you seems to be messing with a lot of rule regarding the use of EDT.

Comment: @ Mathias the combo is populated in the FillP() method together with txtOFOCode. OFOCode then becomes input for the query that populates OFOOccupation.

Answer (score 1):

If the second thread would have to wait anyway, you can just combine them

```
t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fillP(); // this method produces a string which would be used by the query running in thread 2

        //After fillP() is done, start a new thread
        t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            String search = txtOFOCOde.getText();
            String sql = "Select * from APP.OFOOCCUPATION where OFOOCCUPATIONCODE = '"++"'";
         try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);){
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
            String add1 = rs.getString("OFOOCCUPATIONNAME");
            OFOOccupation.setText(add1);
        }
    }});
```

And making it so complex with nested threads is unnecessary since, well, it is not needed

```
t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            fillP(); // this method produces a string which would be used by the query running in thread 2

        //After fillP() is done, keep going
        String search = txtOFOCOde.getText();
        String sql = "Select * from APP.OFOOCCUPATION where OFOOCCUPATIONCODE = '"++"'";
        try(Connection con =   DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);){
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
            String add1 = rs.getString("OFOOCCUPATIONNAME");
            OFOOccupation.setText(add1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score -2):

No need to use wait and notify...this can be achieved by using a flag and setting it to true when fillP() method completes

`

```
    volatile boolean checkFlag = false;  

    Thread t1;
       Thread t2;
       t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            fillP(); // this method produces a string which would be used by the query running in thread 2
            checkFlag = true;

        }
    });
        t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {

            while(!checkFlag){
                Thread.currentThread.sleep(1000)// sleep for 1 second and then poll 
            }
             String search = txtOFOCOde.getText();
            String sql = "Select * from APP.OFOOCCUPATION where OFOOCCUPATIONCODE = '"++"'";
try(Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MTD","herbert","elsie1*#");
     PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);){
        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()){
            String add1 = rs.getString("OFOOCCUPATIONNAME");
            OFOOccupation.setText(add1);
        }
      }



    }


    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(Person.this, e);
}    
        }
    });
    t1.start();

    t2.start();
```

`

Comment: Have you tested this? It doesn't even compile because checkFlag is modified and isn't declared as final. You should use an `AtomicBoolean` instead.

Comment: Spin-Wait?? Oh, come on !!

Comment: The above code will work if checkFlag is static. Sorry for missing that out but nonethe less this approach is what is required for the problem stated

Comment: No offense, but a spin-wait is the worst working solution to this. It is very expensive. Outside that the OP has a whole bigger problem with his overall design.